# Group Algebra in Matlab

Tags: matlab

What is the best way to implement group algebra using Matlab. More specifically, I only want to work with permutation groups (and their subgroups) but would like a way to find kernels and cosets without coding a brute force version myself.

Comment: Dunno why this was voted to close, but to be clear I'm looking for a point in the direction of some pre-existing package as I haven't been able to find any from an initial Google search.

Comment: Assume that people here know a lot about matlab, but not a lot about your field. Hence it is a very unclear question. You don't even specify 'best' and don't show what you have tried to find so far and why that is not sufficient.

Comment: I take your points but personally I feel the question is clear to someone that did know about the field and it was voted to close before one of those people could potentially answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/) is a 'System for Computational Discrete Algebra' and is able to do all the things requested in the question.